# Button not responding to click with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm new to JQuery and am trying to write a program which returns (console log for testing) the value of a button when it is clicked. For some reason my code does not register when the button is clicked, and additionally I don't think the right value is being parsed for the "car" parameter.

Here is my code (probably more than needed but not sure where I'm going wrong):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(":button").click(myFunction(this.value));
});

function myFunction(car) {
  selection = car;
  console.log(selection);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" name="newButton" value="Mercedes"> <br>
<input type="button" name="newButton" value="BMW"> <br>
<input type="button" name="newButton" value="Audi">
```

I expect the program to log the value of the button that is pressed, however it is currently logging nothing.

Thanks

Comment: ":button" remove the colon (just "button")

Comment: @ControlAltDel Nopes.

Comment: @ControlAltDel He's using `input[type=button]`, not `button`.

Comment: `$("input[type='button']").on('click', myFunction(this.value));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are executing the function there. You should assign it, not execute it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(":button").click(myFunction);
});

function myFunction(event) {
  selection = event.target.value;
  console.log(selection);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" name="newButton" value="Mercedes"> <br>
<input type="button" name="newButton" value="BMW"> <br>
<input type="button" name="newButton" value="Audi">
```

You can use the above way, or better, this way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(":button").click(e => myFunction(e.target.value));
});

function myFunction(car) {
  selection = car;
  console.log(selection);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" name="newButton" value="Mercedes"> <br>
<input type="button" name="newButton" value="BMW"> <br>
<input type="button" name="newButton" value="Audi">
```

Comment: You are logging the click event.

Comment: @connexo Updated. Check.

Comment: @connexo Yep, same here. I have corrected it as soon as I found it.

Comment: Not sure why this answer is attracting so many downvotes, in spite of being right. I would be very happy to know the reason behind it.

Comment: It makes zero sense to name the argument `car` in `myFunction(car)` in your first sample.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Welcome, I was also shocked that people downvoted instead of editing it due to naming convention :)

Comment: @RohitSharma Thanks for the support mate... 

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy without any help of jQuery:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { // native way to do $(document).ready(function() {
  // get a list of all buttons and iterate over it
  for (const btn of document.querySelectorAll('input[type=button]')) {
    // and add a click listener to each one of them
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      console.log(btn.value);  
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="button" name="newButton" value="Mercedes"> <br>
<input type="button" name="newButton" value="BMW"> <br>
<input type="button" name="newButton" value="Audi">
```